# Highlight duplicate cells where a cell in another column is also duplicate

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, duplicates, conditional-formatting, countif

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: example]

Where I want to highlight cells on columns B-E when they're not unique but **also** are part of the same "category" (i.e. their row in column A is also the same). So for example, D8 doesn't get highlighted because there's no other 11 part of the Alpha category.

Maybe I'm searching for this wrong but haven't been able to found an example or something similar online. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF($A$2:$A&$B$2:$E, $A2&B2)>1)*($A2<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Should note (even though it's pictured) that the range should go from B2 (I had it from A2 and it wasn't working). Thank you!